# Encapsulated OrderedDict in a Dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ordereddictionary

When encapsulating a `OrderedDict` into a `dict` there occurs a problem where the `OrderedDict` is not updated.

The aim is to get a dictonary with the form:

```
{name1: OrderedDict( {year1:amount,year2:amount,...}), name2: OrderedDict( {year1:amount,year2:amount,...})}
```

However after initializing the first `temp_ord`, it is not further updated and therefore the year-amount pairs are the same for every name after the first.

The CSV-structure is in columns: name year number. I am not sure if this is a looping mistake or it is because of the encapsulating of the dicts.

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

def plot_names(file_name, names):
    temp_dict = {}
    temp_ord = OrderedDict({})
    with open(file_name) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for name in names:
            for row in reader:
                if name == row["name"]:
                    temp_ord[row["year"]] = row["number"]
            temp_dict[name] = temp_ord
    return temp_dict
```

Data Format:

```
year    name    gender  number /n 1993  Abarna  f   1 /n 1993   Abetare f   1 /n 1993   Abir    f   1
```

Comment: can you show your data?

Comment: It is updated. You're seeing all of the *last* data, because **they all reference the same object**. Move `temp_ord = OrderedDict()` (the extra dictionary was unnecessary) *inside the loop*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe in which loop exactly, could you provide the fixed loops ?

Comment: Well, for which loop do you want a fresh dictionary for each item? This isn't a code-writing service, you have to do some of the work yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, I tried putting it in both loops, which gives me still two errors: If put in inner loop, I get empty OrderedDict for every Name. If put into the outer loop I get an empty OrderedDict for every after the first name. When providing an answer you could at least give a reference to which loop you meant and not reference just to "the loop", therefore my previous answer.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment. You have other problems than the multiple references; you know a reader can only be consumed once?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well thank you if you would just have told me that(reader can only be consumed once), I would have been able to fix the problem instantly.

Comment: I hadn't spotted that problem until you said that moving the dictionary inside the loop made most of them empty. This is why a [mcve] would be useful, as it isolates a single problem. Glad you fixed it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a reader can only be consumed once (thanks @jonrsharpe).

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

def plot_names(file_name, names):
    temp_dict = {}
    for name in names:
            with open(file_name) as csvfile:
                reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                temp_ord = OrderedDict({})
                for row in reader:
                    if name == row["name"]:
                        temp_ord[row["year"]] = row["number"]
                temp_dict[name] = temp_ord
    return temp_dict
```